# Undefined control sequence in math mode

Tags: math-mode

I have been trying to figure out for a while where the problem is but I have no clue. I get the following message: "Undefined control sequence. The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}."

My writing:
The paper focuses on the following setting:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Causal inference problem with treatment indicator 
$Z \in\left \{ 0,1 \right \}$ representing control or intervention, 
potential outcomes $Y\left ( 1 \right ) \in \mathbb{R}$ under 
intervention and  $Y\left ( 0  \right ) \in \mathbb{R}$ under 
control, and a set of observed covariates $X \in \mathcal{X} 
\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{d}$.
\item Independence assumption $\left \{  Y\left ( 1 \right ), 
Y\left ( 0  \right )\right \} \Perp Z \mid X$
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You probably need `\usepackage{amssymb}`.

Comment: I tried this now but nothing has changed. The message also says: \beamer@doifinframe ... 0 \right )\right \} \Perp 
                                                  Z \mid X$ \end {itemize} \...
l.265 \end{frame}
                 
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Comment: Okay. Please provide a complete, minimal example that replicates your behaviour. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Can you do that?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of making your code minimally compilable. Feel free to revert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a typo toward the end of your document snippet. If I make your document minimally compilable, I get the following error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\beamer@doifinframe ... 0 \right )\right \} \Perp 
                                                  Z \mid X$ \end {itemize} \...
l.10 \end{frame}
```

The culprit is `\Perp`. If I replace it with `\perp`, the document compiles fine:

[image]

Incidentally, who taught you to grossly over-use `\left` and `\right`? Your brief  code snippet contains six [!] instances of both directives, and they achieve *absolutely nothing* except (a) interfere with good spacing around the delimiters and (b) create an amazing amount of code clutter.

Comment: Extra +1 for the last comment. I'm currently cleaning a manuscript that does the same. Is so tempted to to just start each chapter by removing them all and the put in the very few that are relevant as we go along

Comment: Thank you, this worked!